# What is the sequence of operations in ORDER BY clause of SQL query with a session variable in the field list?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, session-variables, mysql-5.6

Usin MySQL 5.6, I have a table `test_ap` with 6 rows of sample data

```
CREATE TABLE `test_ap` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`some_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO test_ap VALUES
(1,'2016-06-30'),(2,'2005-12-31'),(3,'2012-09-30'),(4,'2015-12-31'),(5,'2011-03-31'),(6,'2013-03-28');
```

I run following 2 queries :

```
SET @a = 0;
SELECT @a, id, @a := @a + id new, some_date FROM test_ap ORDER BY some_date;
```

and get the result

```
+------+----+------+------------+
| @a   | id | new  | some_date  |
+------+----+------+------------+
|    0 |  2 |    2 | 2005-12-31 |
|    2 |  5 |    7 | 2011-03-31 |
|    7 |  3 |   10 | 2012-09-30 |
|   10 |  6 |   16 | 2013-03-28 |
|   16 |  4 |   20 | 2015-12-31 |
|   20 |  1 |   21 | 2016-06-30 |
+------+----+------+------------+
```

As far as I know, ORDER BY clause works after the result set is fetched. Then how is the session variable in the field-list getting modified according to that order done at the end, and not by default (primary-key) order?

I tried the following to understand the sequence of operations.

```
SET @a = NULL;
SELECT @a, id, @a := some_date, some_date FROM test_ap ORDER BY @a;
SELECT @a;
```

In this case now, I can see that somehow the row for id 1 is fetched first, but the others are ordered (in ascending) as per the dates of the remaining rows; and @a is holding the value of the last row date.

```
+------+----+-----------------+------------+
| @a   | id | @a := some_date | some_date  |
+------+----+-----------------+------------+
| NULL |  1 | 2016-06-30      | 2016-06-30 |
| 2005 |  3 | 2012-09-30      | 2012-09-30 |
| 2011 |  6 | 2013-03-28      | 2013-03-28 |
| 2012 |  4 | 2015-12-31      | 2015-12-31 |
| 2015 |  5 | 2011-03-31      | 2011-03-31 |
| 2016 |  2 | 2005-12-31      | 2005-12-31 |
+------+----+-----------------+------------+

+------------+
| @a         |
+------------+
| 2013-03-28 |
+------------+
```

Can anyone explain these phenomena? What is the sequence of operations regarding fetching the result set, ordering it, and setting the session variable?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, ORDER BY clause works after the result set is fetched

That's not necessarily the case. The conceptual progression of operations is from, where, group by, having, distinct, order by, limit, but when an index can be used for ordering, the data is read from the table in index order, and in that case the order by has already happened "before" (to use the word casually) the rows are actually read.

In your example, the server appears to be doing exactly as the documentation suggests:

> In a `SELECT` statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client.

This doesn't mean precisely what it appears to say, of course.  The select expression may be evaluated before the result is actually written to the client on the wire, but the timing is not defined.

> This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected

Your rows are ordered by the value of `@a` as it existed when each row was read from the table, which in this case seems to have been in primary key order, so the value of @a for id 1 is null, for id 2 it is the value assigned for id 1, id 3 matches the value from id 2, etc.

Even though standard SQL has no sense of left-to-right, `@a` changes its value in the middle of the row, here, due to `:=`.

> What is the sequence of operations

Undefined.

What you are doing is fundamentally problematic, for the reason you are observing.  A query like this isn't guaranteed to keep working, even if it works, now, since it is the optimizer's job to find a way to do the least amount of work possible, and the optimizer learns new tricks with each major release.

See [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), the source of the quotes above and below.

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> `SET @a = @a + 1;
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.
>
> ...
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.